# How to add another row to a bindingsource ? 'Objects added to a BindingSource's list must all be of the same type.'

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to update a bindingsource with new rows of data from a DataTable.
However, even if I try to add the exact same DataTable twice to my bindingsource, I have the following error message:

> "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Objects added to a BindingSource's
>   list must all be of the same type.'"

```
public BindingSource bindingSourceDataTable = new BindingSource(); 

bindingSourceDataTable.DataSource = myDataTable;
bindingSourceDataTable.Add(myDataTable);  ==>> This line will throw the ERROR.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've already added your binding source and set the data source to `myDataTable`. If you want to add new rows, you should add them to your datatable, eg:

`myDataTable.Rows.Add()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `myDataTable` has type `List<int>`, you are setting `DataSource` to `myDataTable`, which means `bindingSourceDataTable` is a list of `int`. By doing `bindingSourceDataTable.Add(myDataTable)` you are attempting to add a `List<int>`, but as mentioned before it contains `int`, hence the error.